# given data samples, deducing approximate formula by programming?

Tags: python, math, automation, formula

Given a sample formula `'y=2x+1`' we can get y when we know x with a defined '`function`', for example in python

```
def y(x):   return 2*x + 1

x :   1    2    3     4     5     ...
y :   3    5    7     9     11    ...
```

Can I do it reversed? Given data samples and get the approximate formula?

```
x :   1.001    2.12    3.1     4.001     5.021     ...
y :   3.002    5.23    7.2     9.002     11.32    . ..
```

Of course, it is easily to draw all points by coordinates and link those points to get approximate formula then guess the result when people to solve this, but how do it by programming?

Any keywords can search or libs can use?

Thank you.

=====

Many thanks for everyone. After searching a bit with information you shared, it is a BIGG...G area without a simple solution -_-!.

Technically, I realized what I need should be "`polynomial fitting`" given the difference of `Polynomial regression/ Polynomial interpolation/ polynomial approximation`......

I will give the credit to Gerard, and again, thanks all for your help.

Comment: This is much too broad a question for SO, but the technique you are looking for is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Comment: Do you always expect a straight line ? If not, the question is rather broad, but if it is the case, the answers you already have are exactly what you need.

Comment: @Cimbali, not only a straight line I expected, but might be curved line in a given range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i would say the problem looks more like [polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation)
In python you have many libs dealing with that, for example high level [scipy.interpolate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/interpolate.html)
or you can do it "by hand" like [these examples](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/rjleveque/8798427)

In any case, you will need some maths !

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I understood your question, you want to retrieve the equation of the line that fits your data, right?

In case this is your question, you can use `polyfit` from the package `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np
x = [1.001, 2.12, 3.1, 4.001, 5.021]
y = [3.002, 5.23, 7.2, 9.002, 11.32]
np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

The returned values are:

```
array([ 2.05658156,  0.88110544])
```

This means that the equation of the line is:

```
y = 2.05658156x + 0.88110544
```

Comment: Hi Po6, thanks for sharing, your sample is good for a straight line, i am in exploring whether np have 'curved line related' polyfit

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need NumPy and SciPy packages. For example, see `Linear Regression` docs for SciPy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html